# Use the binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the binomial theorem to show that $C(n,0) + C(n,1)+.....+C(n,n)=2^n$ for all nonnegative integers n. I was hoping if someone could give me a hint on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? Write it down. Does any part of it look like the left? What part? How much? Alternately, does any part of it look like the right? What part? How much?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$(1+x)^n=C(n,0)+C(n,1)x+C(n,2)x^2+\cdots C(n,n-1)x^{n-1}+C(n,n)x^n$$
by [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).